# Is there any package in Python to copy each PDF Page and Paste as Image in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, pdf-conversion

My requirement is to copy each PDF Page and paste into excel as an image. I have tried using **pdftables_api** and **tabula** . The output i am getting is of text and the alignment is completely different. Is there any package or script to get output in the desired format which i have mentioned below?

**Input:**

[image]

**Output which i need:**

[image]

**Output which i got using Python Packages:**

[image]

Need support on this :)

Comment: We do not offer general project support on Stack Overflow. You have to ask a specific on-topic question. Recommendations for libraries are not considered on-topic BTW.

Comment: Ohh. Alright :)

Comment: if you need images then use program which convert images - ie. [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) should convert `PDF` to `png`/`jpg` - probably even using simple `convert file.pdf image.png`. And you can use it with Python using `subprocess`. Eventually there should be Python's  wrapper on `imagemagick` - probably `wand`